# Open specific Facebook profile from Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, xamarin

I've been trying to use deep-linking to open up specific profile pages on the Facebook app, but so far it will only open my own profile. The general format should be `fb://profile/<id>` unfortunately every time I use this I am directed to a page that says `Profile Unavailable`. The specific example I am using is with my colleagues ID so from my app if I wanted to go to his page I would open the URL for `fb://profile/10206768458598300`. Is there a new format for finding profiles? I have found no other solution for opening a Facebook profile from within my app besides opening an actual webpage, having the user sign-in, and go to the actual profile URL of the person.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have any officially supported way to open a profile in the Facebook app.